# vb.net .VerifyDatabase for Crystal Reports using a password restricted Access DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

As the question title suggests, my vb.net project that uses Crystal Reports 9 and a password restricted MS-Access 97 database.

When loading reports, the `Load` method calls `cReport.VerifyDatabase()` which has previously been working fine without a password, but since adding one, it isn't working, and gives me the following error

> Log on failed.
>      at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.VerifyDatabase()

What do I need to add/change to this code for it to log on successfully?

```
Private Sub frmReportViewer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        setFormSizes(Me, con)
        Me.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2), 10)
        Me.Text = "Report Viewer - (" & Replace(cReport.FileName, "rassdk://", "") & ")"

        cReport.VerifyDatabase()
        cReport.Refresh()

        crViewer.ReportSource = cReport
        crViewer.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
        crViewer.Zoom(87)

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex)

    End Try
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

The data can be viewed when opening the report file in Crystal Reports itself, but this is because I can manually enter the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288359(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
 Dim logOnInfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To cReport.Database.Tables.Count - 1
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Database_Name"
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password"
            cReport.Database.Tables.Item(i).ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo)
        Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation : [1.4.4.1.2](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/crnet13_sp14_dg_en.pdf)

Use this method to log database with your report before verify the database :

```
    Private Function SubreportLogon_RD(ByVal TestReport As ReportDocument)  As ReportDocument
 Dim dataSourceConnections As DataSourceConnections =  TestReport.DataSourceConnections
 Dim connectInfo As IConnectionInfo = dataSourceConnections(0)
 connectInfo.SetConnection("ServerName", "DatabaseName", "UserName",    "Password")

 Dim TestSubreport As ReportDocument = TestReport.Subreports("Subreport1")
 Dim subreportDataSourceConnections As DataSourceConnections = TestSubreport.DataSourceConnections
 Dim connectInfo As IConnectionInfo = subreportDataSourceConnections(0)
 connectInfo.SetLogon("UserName", "Password")
End Function
```

Comment: A bit confused about this... Why is connectInfo being declared twice?

Comment: Because you init the report dataconnection, and then the subreport dataconnection :) If you don't use a subreport just init the `DataSourceConnections` of your report.